# How to delay execution until all threads have ramped up

Tags: jmeter

I am using an ultimate thread group to log in  1000 users in a period of 30 minutes. Only after all the users have logged in do I want to execute further scenarios.

The way I thought about doing this was to start a global timer and delay each thread for 30 minutes - (current time - start time) e.g. test starts at 9am and thread 1 completes login in 10 seconds so it would be delayed for 30 minutes - (9:00:10 - 9:00:00) i.e. 29 minutes and 50 seconds. And for example thread 500 would start at 9.15 and login takes 30 seconds then the delay for this thread would be 30 minutes - (9:15:45 - 9:00:00) i.e. 14 minutes and 15 seconds. In this way after 30 minutes I'll have 1000 users all logged in ready to execute the next steps. Does this make sense?

Is there are a more elegant way of doing this perhaps with built in JMeter functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong timer, the easier solution would be going for [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

1. Add it as a child of the second sampler (or whatever is doing the real stuff after the login)
2. Set "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" to `1000`

This way the ramp-up/login will happen according to the ultimate thread group schedule and after that JMeter will wait until there will be 1000 active threads at the location of the Synchronizing Timer and once there are 1000 users - they will be released at exactly the same moment.

More information: [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

Comment: Yes, not long after asking my question I looked through all the timers and found this one. It's working fine. Thanks